# Reading byte[] data from UDPClient?

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp

I'm learning C# for a project, and so far I've successfully sent and received simple values using UDPClient (Strings, doubles etc.), but I'm having trouble finding a way to handle multiple values of different types through byte[].

Most of the examples I've found here and elsewhere usually handle one type of data, eg.:

```
byte[] messageToSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Gutentagen");

// Send value through UDPClient, then receiving side...

byte [] messageReceived = udpClientReceiver.EndReceive(res, ref remoteIpEndPoint);

var message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageReceived);
```

This is all fine and good for sending single values, but I would like the packet to contain multiple values, maybe in the future of different data types. Specifically I need to send a packet of six doubles, three for Cartesian coordinates and three to make up a Quaternion.

I have a vague notion that MemoryStream is going to be involved, but I haven't seen a concrete example of receiving more than one value from UDPClient.

Is MemoryStream the right approach? Does anyone know of any examples in C# using UDPClient where the program receives more than trivial information (for example, it receives a string, a float and a char every packet)?

Comment: You need to define an application/framing protocol that describes your message format. That you read that through a MemoryStream is an implementation detail, you may as well pluck the contents from the byte array directly.

Comment: Questions asking for references are off-topic on Stack Overflow. It's possible to wrap a `byte[]` in a `MemoryStream`, then use `BinaryReader` to read data from the stream, or you can just use `BitConverter` to read directly from the `byte[]`. There are lots of other options too, but those seem like the most obvious to me. Please try _something_, and then if you still have a question, post it along with [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing clearly what you've tried, explaining what the code does and how that's different from what you want.